# Can't create proxy for external service to get around CORS

Tags: angular, proxy, cors

I have been tasked with adding a third party vendor's chat service to our web app. The only instructions the vendor have provided was to add a div and a script to our web app. When doing so I am getting this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://chatserver11.thevendor.io/visitor.ashx?siteId=12345678'
from origin 'https://localhost:44419' has been blocked by CORS policy:
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

After reading through [this Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i) I figured it was a proxy error.

We are already using a proxy service, SpaProxy, with our angular front end to connect to our dotnet backend and other external APIs. The problem is I can not figure out how to configure the proxy for `https://chatserver11.thevendor.io`. The script that is provided never references that url. It does mention some similar ones like `https://standby.thevendorvue.com` and `https://vue.thevendor.com` which I have been able to add to our proxy configuration, but I can't add the "chatserver11" because it must be coming from something external.

Here is the javascript they provided us:

```
var TheVendorAPI = TheVendorAPI || {};
(function (t) {
  function e(e) {
    var a = document.createElement("script"),
      c = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    a.type = "text/javascript", a.async = !0, a.src = e + t.site_id, c.parentNode.insertBefore(a, c)
  }
  t.chat_buttons = t.chat_buttons || [], t.chat_buttons.push({
    code_plan: "6e5d0fc9-fake-4b4d-971a-55baa3d026a3",
    div_id: "thevendor-button-6e5d0fc9-fake-4b4d-971a-55baa3d026a3"
  }),
    t.site_id = 12345678,
    t.main_code_plan = "6e5d0fc9-fake-4b4d-971a-55baa3d026a3",
    e("/api/chat/vue/livechat.ashx?siteId="),  // using our proxy

    setTimeout(function () {
      t.loaded || e("/api/chat/standby/livechat.ashx?siteId=")  // also using our proxy
    }, 5e3)
})(TheVendorAPI || {})
```

**Update:**

I installed the CORS unblock plugin and now it is working but I am getting a different 403 error I am trying to debug.